Is my tub draining properly?
Please see a video of my tub. Is this noise normal? I am not a plumber by any means, but I am worried there might be an issue with the slope of the drain pipes and this is irregular draining due to that. I appreciate any feedback.
Edits:

This is a newly installed tub with a newly installed drain. There are no hair wads there.


clogged air vent

Important factors are missing: has it always been this way? Did this happen when the home or install had an inspection? Is this the only slow-draining fixture in the house?

@AdamO This is a new tub in a new home. This just happened for the first time when I filled it up. Do you think it's truly slow draining? If so, what could the issues be considering it's a completely newly installed tub.

@Manny Was it in your inspection report?

Nope, I just found it out myself @AdamO

@Manny sounds like it was a lousy inspection - which I'm sorry for, but I suggest you to call out a plumber to do an inspection because it's peace of mind. They will likely find out the tub's issue straight away, as well as do such things as assessing the pitch of the main drainpipe, the adequacy of water pressure, state of water heater, etc. New homes definitely should be independently inspected.

The noise is not normal, but more importantly the drain rate is not normal. There should be a nice whirlpool and the sound should be of rushing water. Piping slope seems unlikely - there is a p-trap here so the water drains via syphon action and the weight of the water in the tub. If you mean the sewer connection is sloped due to geologic movement, you would have the issue at multiple fixtures and other issues as well. First, snake the trap with a little $2 plastic tool - are there big wads of hair stuck in the trap? Then fill and drain to retest. If the issue persists, consult a plumber. (Clogged air vent is worth considering as noted in comments).

The issue is this is a new tub in a new home and the drain was not used before, so there shouldn't be any hair stuck there. There's also no issues around the house elsewhere, so it isn't the sewer connection. What do you think it could be?

@Manny excluding the possibility of clog should be your first objective.

@Manny  Hair is commonly at fault, but is not the only cause of a clog.  The installers might have dropped something in the pipe by mistake/forgot to remove a rag/something.  Tubs/sinks have smaller pipes than the main drain/toilet.
